# Attempting to change Wifi SSID causes CPU blowout / unresponsiveness (17.10)

Tags: wireless, 17.10, cpu-load, gnome-shell

Have just recently acquired a basic HP Laptop with a relatively low-spec AMD processor (E2-7110 APU). I'm now dual-booting Ubuntu 17.10 with Windows 10.

Today, I had the machine at work with me, and our BYOD-Wifi was playing up. It usually requires the use of a captive portal before internet access is gained, but with no internet access available due to a network fault I wanted to switch SSID's to the one running on my cellphone (wifi tethering).
Clicking on the menu top-right and selecting (current SSID -> Select Network) caused gnome-shell to immediately run up to 100% CPU and sit there pegged. To the point where I I would move the mouse and the pointer would catch up some 15-20 seconds later. It took several minutes but I got things to stop pegging by clicking 'cancel' (very, very slowly).

Having just tried to repeat the process at home, i'm not seeing the same behavior, and a browse through syslog is confusing (lots of interesting stuff associated with gnome-shell in the syslog, but not much I can directly tie to wifi. Perhaps:

```
Nov  6 09:44:17 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-4611354)
Nov  6 09:44:28 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-8804218)
Nov  6 09:44:28 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-7839245)
Nov  6 09:44:37 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-6094954)
Nov  6 09:44:47 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-895357)
Nov  6 09:45:13 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-6372126)
Nov  6 09:45:32 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-7579487)
Nov  6 09:45:51 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: libinput error: libinput bug: timer: offset negative (-7376184)
```

Elsewhere in the log (same PID) I see stack errors for various .jsm's (I assumed these were firefox or thunderbird errors, such as this:

```
Nov  6 09:34:16 skyraider org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1180]: Extension error: TypeError: settings is undefined moz-extension://f2c1761c-28d5-4d3e-a904-1da72c8bb176/js/background.js 611
```

But I also found this interesting:

```
Nov  6 09:34:26 skyraider gnome-shell[1180]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
```

... basically I have no idea why it happened and wondered if it was something worth mentioning or pursuing. The laptop is quite underpowered (even under relatively routine workloads it can become unresponsive briefly and thrash the (old, spinning) disk for long moments before becoming properly responsive again) but this was about as bad as i've had it yet.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thanks for providing all this information. Anyway please try to shorten your question a bit .. it takes very long until one gets what really happens ;)